# Postfix headers: Put FROM into REPLY-TO and change FROM

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I've configured Postfix to use SMTP through another relay host. Now I need to change the email headers in order to be accepted by the relay host because the application which runs on my server is an obsolete management software that puts the user's email address into the `FROM` header (this is dumb and a reason to get rejected) - since I don't have the time to change the code, I want to force Postfix to alter the headers. What I'm trying to achieve:

1. The current `FROM` header should be moved into the `REPLY-TO` header
2. The `FROM` header should be set per default using the same email address for every outgoing message

Regarding the second point - I've figured out how to do it, simply by putting the following contents into `/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps` and `/etc/postfix/header_check` (and by updating `main.cf` of course):

```
# /etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps
/.+/    newsender@address.com
# /etc/postfix/header_check
/From:.*/ REPLACE From: newsender@address.com
```

But the first point is causing me problems - how can this be done with Postfix? How can I put the current `FROM` header into the `REPLY-TO` header?

Comment: Try to be more specific about which field is set to what (is it *only* the header that is wrong, or also the envelope sender?). If you `REPLACE` a header, then postfix will still fixup missing headers afterwards, so just replacing the `From:` with `Reply-To:` might be sufficient.

Comment: @anx the current data that is put by the application in `FROM` should move to `REPLY-TO` and how I set the `FROM` (which automatically sets the `envelope-from` as well) has been done already :) Do you know how I could replace the `From:` with `Reply-To:`?

Comment: Put another way: Why is `/From:(.*)/  REPLACE Reply-To:$1` not your solution?